# how to use special characters in windows forms application/report

Tags: .net, special-characters, windows-forms-designer, exponent

I need to use a special character (an exponent of two, aka ^2) in a windows forms application. I also need to use it in a Microsoft Report that is opened by this same windows forms application.

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start + Run, Charmap.exe.  In the "Search for" box type "two", Search.  Should be the 2nd character.  Click it, Select, Copy.  Switch to your code or report and hit Ctrl+V.